# Flutter Build Apk Error clip board plugin error

Tags: flutter, apk, build-error

I Trying To Build flutter apk for publish in play store but showing some error :

PS E:\Flutter_Project\romantic_shayari> flutter build apk

Running "flutter pub get" in romantic_shayari...                    0.7s
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
To generate an app bundle, run:
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
To split the APKs per ABI, run:
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Note: C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\facebook_audience_network-0.7.1\android\src\main\java\com\dsi\facebook_audience_network\FacebookInStreamVideoAdPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 89KB to 63KB: Removed 29%

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':clipboard_manager:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> C:\Users\appde.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

```
 C:\Users\appde\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a528b13ac93e64cafa3d0480e2c93207\core-1.1.0\res\values\values.xml:142:5-173:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 51s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     172.3s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating `android\settings_aar.gradle`...                      534ms
√ `android\settings_aar.gradle` created successfully.
Building plugin clipboard_manager...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                   38.3s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'clipboard_manager'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 37s

The plugin clipboard_manager could not be built due to the issue above.
PS E:\Flutter_Project\romantic_shayari>

This error show when I try to build apk

[image]